# Why does my Java list behave differently when defining it directly as opposed to when I parse user input with Scanner into a list?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, binary-tree

I've written a Java class that constructs a binary tree based on a given in-order traversal sequence and pre-order traversal sequence, both passed as arrays. The tree is constructed perfectly when I pass arrays that were defined like this:

```
String inOrder[] = new String[] {"2","5","6","10","12","14","15"};
String preOrder[] = new String[] {"10","5","2","6","14","12","15"};
```

But I get the error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when I pass arrays that were defined with user input using the Scanner like this:

```
System.out.println("Enter the preorder separated by ONLY commas (no spaces): ");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String preOrderScan = scanner.nextLine().toString();
System.out.println("Enter the inorder separated by ONLY commas (no spaces): ");
String inOrderScan = scanner.nextLine().toString();
scanner.close();

String preOrder[] = preOrderScan.split(",");
String inOrder[] = inOrderScan.split(",");
```

When prompted, I enter the following characters for preOrder and inOrder, each followed by hitting enter:

```
10,5,2,6,14,12,15
2,5,6,10,12,14,15
```

This is the code where I create an instance of the ConstructTree class and call the build() function with these arrays passed as parameters as well as the starting/ending indices:

```
ConstructTree tree = new ConstructTree();
int len = inOrder.length;

//Build the tree
Node<String> root = tree.build(inOrder, preOrder, 0, len - 1);
```

And this is the ConstructTree class with the build() function and a helper function for returning the index of a given element in the inOrder array. I have commented the lines where the error is thrown:

```
public class ConstructTree {

     //A variable representing the current index in the preOrder array for creating new nodes recursively
     static int preOrderIndex = 0;

     /*This function recursively builds the tree with a given inOrder array, preOrder array and indices 
      * representing the start and end of a given array or sub-array */
     public Node<String> build (String[] inOrder, String[] preOrder, int inOrderStart, int inOrderEnd) {

         //Returns null if no new node needs to be created
         if (inOrderStart > inOrderEnd) return null;

         //Creates a new node containing the value in current index of of preOrder
         Node<String> newNode = new Node<String>(preOrder[preOrderIndex++]); //ERROR IS THROWN ON THIS LINE

         //Return the current node if it has no children
         if (inOrderStart == inOrderEnd) return newNode;

         //Call the helper function to find the index in the inOrder array containing newNode.data
         int inOrderIndex = assignInOrderIndex(inOrder, inOrderStart, inOrderEnd, newNode.data);

         //Recursive calls to build left and right children of the current node
         newNode.left = build(inOrder, preOrder, inOrderStart, inOrderIndex - 1); //ERROR IS ALSO THROWN ON THIS LINE FOR EVERY RECURSIVE CALL
         newNode.right = build(inOrder, preOrder, inOrderIndex + 1, inOrderEnd);

         //Return the current node
         return newNode;
     }

     //A helper function to assign the inOrderIndex variable to the index containing the given string
     int assignInOrderIndex(String[] inOrder, int inOrderStart, int inOrderEnd, String lookFor) {

         int i;

         for (i = inOrderStart; i <= inOrderEnd; i++) {

             if (inOrder[i] == lookFor) return i;

         }

         return i;

     }

 }
```

I've checked the arrays produced by parsing the input so many different ways to verify that they only contain the exact sequence of strings as when I define them using the previous method, and they appear to be exactly the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: Post your algorithm for binary search tree construct

Comment: At first glance it looks the same, have you compared the string array with `Arrays.toString(preOrder)` after the input from the scanner?

Comment: Do you write something before these numbers into the console?

Comment: You say that you're getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` but you didn't provide the actual code where that happens. Also the `toString()` is redundant, as `scanner.nextLine()` already gives you a `String`.

Comment: Could you show the part of the code that throws the exception?

Comment: Hey I just added the rest of the code. I'm not sure if you all receive a notification when I edit the post or not so I'm leaving this comment also just in case. Thanks!